# Spring4 + OAuth2 + CXF/JAXRS + Keycloak

Tags: java, spring, jax-rs, cxf, keycloak

I'm got stuck when trying to implement oauth2 usage in my java spring microservice. Almost EVERY article (regarding examples) I've found was about Spring Boot and oauth2. But I have a simple Java CXF/JAXRS microservice with a springSecurity.xml
For a better understanding what I want to achieve: I have a Java microservice which might communicate with other microserices. It doesn't have any frontend, it's just a backend service. It includes openAPI/swagger for documentationen purposes and use swagger-ui (included via maven plugin) to test the endpoints. I know that configuring swagger-ui is another step I have to take later on. First of all I would like to secure my microservice with oauth2.

All I found which at least looked a little bit like what I'm looking for was this:
https://github.com/tfeng/play-oauth2/blob/master/conf/spring/security-context.xml
My previous security-context.xml looked like this:

```
    <sec:http pattern="/rest/**">
        <sec:csrf disabled="true" />
        <sec:intercept-url access="isAuthenticated()"
                           pattern="/**" />
        <sec:http-basic />
    </sec:http>

    <sec:http>
        <sec:csrf disabled="true" />
        <sec:intercept-url access="isAuthenticated()"
                           pattern="/**" />
        <sec:http-basic />
        <sec:logout />
    </sec:http>

    <sec:authentication-manager>
        <sec:authentication-provider>
            <sec:user-service>
                <sec:user authorities="" name="myApiUser" password="my4p1Secr3t" />
            </sec:user-service>
        </sec:authentication-provider>
    </sec:authentication-manager>
```

In best case i can configure my microservice and swagger-ui to use Keycloak for authentication/authorization.

I would be glad if someone could help me out and point me into the right direction. Maybe with some steps or explanation for more clarification.

Comment: Sorry but your question does not follow the SO requirements (i.e. your question cannot be responded) but Keycloak contains a lot of examples https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak-quickstarts (take a look to app-authz-jee...).

Comment: Very broad question, I have worked with keycloak before and I might be able to help out, but you got to get into the details, and have more specific questions, I'd recommend reading on the documtation - not the implemented examples - and have an Idea about the standards and the known endpoints, I agree that there are multiple examples and I remember that there is a springboot starter dependency for keycloak, it can be quite confusing.. get yourself familiar with standalone keycloak auth and you'll find the right questions to ask. 
Think in terms of the **WHAT** and then ask about the **HOW**

Comment: I really appreciate your feedback and will have a look in the examples.

@SaleemKhair: thx for the advice. I think I know what I want to achieve but it's hard to put it in words :( My main point is that I try to let my backend microservices speak oauth2 but I cannot find any example which is not based on springboot :( I have the situation here where I cannot use springboot for some reasons.

Comment: @Stoffelchen any luck?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using spring xml configurations, and as I understood you want to manually define the configs that springboot's auto-configs and scans does.
First of all, you'll need to component-scan the keycloak package `org.keycloak.adapters.springsecurity` assuming you have the dependency defined in your pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.keycloak</groupId>
    <artifactId>keycloak-spring-security-adapter</artifactId>
    <version>14.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

To secure an application with Spring Security you have to provide some extra beans in your Spring Security configuration file and add the Keycloak security filter to your pipeline:

- In order for Single Sign Out work properly you have to define a session listener, ether as a spring bean wraped in a `ServletListenerRegistrationBean<HttpSessionEventPublisher>` object
  Or in your web.xml file for pure spring security environment.

```
<listener>
     <listener-class>org.springframework.security.web.session.HttpSessionEventPublisher</listener-class>
</listener>
```

- Now that you have your listener inplace and the keycloak beans scanned you can start defining your authentication manager and provider.

```xml
<security:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
        <security:authentication-provider ref="keycloakAuthenticationProvider" />
    </security:authentication-manager>

    <bean id="keycloakAuthenticationProvider" class="org.keycloak.adapters.springsecurity.authentication.KeycloakAuthenticationProvider" />
```

- Your json configs for your client application are loaded via the `adapterDeploymentContext` bean, it specifies how the client should comunicate with the auth-server.

```xml
<bean id="adapterDeploymentContext" class="org.keycloak.adapters.springsecurity.AdapterDeploymentContextFactoryBean">
        <constructor-arg value="/WEB-INF/keycloak.json" />
    </bean>
```

Here is an example for that json file, for a project called plantarium,

```json
{
  "realm" : "plantarium",
  "resource" : "plantarium-plants",
  "use-resource-role-mappings" : true,
  "auth-server-url" : "${env.AUTH_SERVER_URL:http://0.0.0.0:8080/auth}",
  "ssl-required" : "external",
  "enable-cors" : true,
  "cors-max-age" : 1000,
  "cors-allowed-methods" : "POST, PUT, DELETE, GET",
  "cors-exposed-headers" : "WWW-Authenticate, My-custom-exposed-Header",
  "bearer-only" : false,
  "expose-token" : true,
  "principal-attribute": "preferred_username",
  "verify-token-audience" : false,
  "connection-pool-size" : 20,
  "disable-trust-manager": true,
  "allow-any-hostname" : false,
  "token-minimum-time-to-live" : 10,
  "min-time-between-jwks-requests" : 10,
  "public-key-cache-ttl": 86400,
  "confidential-port": 0
}
```

This is what I'm able to give you to replace springboot annotation configs for now, this and the following should help you use keycloack with plain old spring xml based client,

The rest of the xml can be found here: https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/securing_apps/#_spring_secUrity_adapter. which is basically defining filters and endpoints which I believe its going to be specific to your needs. After this you should be able to run your client without any auto-config annotations or springboot starters.

Comment: Sry for my late response :) that what you suggested was exacly what I have been trying :) in the end I managed to get it working :) thx for your support